# Unable to redirect from Community to Salesforce Org

Tags: community, lightning-web-components, lightningnavigation

Error when trying to jump between Community to Salesforce org.

I am using a custom layout template and am not using the navigation menu.

I tried this but this redirected me to the portal

`{
    type: 'comm__loginPage',
    attributes: {
        actionName: 'login'
    }
}`

I would like to be redirected to the Salesforce Org

Comment: I suggest that you use the type as webpage and redirect to home page of your org, use the full URL of your org. The one you have written will redirect to community login page.

Comment: That would be a good solution unfortunately I would have to create a custom label or custom setting each time I switched from DEV, SIT, UAT and production ORG.  I was hoping there was a type that would redirect to my salesforce org

Comment: You can use `URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().toExternalForm()` to get current org base url and redirect there.

Comment: I had to add that code to an APEX class and then wire it to my lwc class but it worked like a charm.  Thanks @manjit5190!!!